# Hide all divs and show ones with same class of checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to build a filter.
There is an item list with a static item class, and dynamically generated item class.

```
<div class="itemswrap">
 <div class="item dynamic1"></div>
 <div class="item dynamic2"></div>
 <div class="item dynamic3"></div>
 <div class="item dynamic2"></div>
</div>
```

There is also a filter menu in a sidebar with dynamically generated id's

```
<ul class="subnav">
  <li class="lifilter">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="dynamic1" />
    <label for="dynamic1">whatever label</label>
  </li>
  <li class="lifilter">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="dynamic2" />
    <label for="dynamic1">whatever label</label>
  </li>
  <li class="lifilter">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="dynamic3" />
    <label for="dynamic1">whatever label</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The idea is to match filter id's with item classes and once a checkbox is checked, only divs with the matching class should be visible.

Here is a js code i came up with

```
$(".lifilter").each(function(){
    var filter1 = $(this).find('.filtercheck').attr('id');
    if ( $(this).find('input.filtercheck').attr('checked') ) 
    {
      $(".itemswrap .item").hide();
      $('.' + filter1).show();
    }
});
```

And nothing happens...

Comment: What is `.productslistdiv` and `.inditem` classes ? And shouldn't you be using the `change` event on your checkboxes ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to show/hide divs on any checkbox state change. Try to wrap your code in the `change` event of you checkboxes :

```
$(".filtercheck").on('change', function(){
    $(".lifilter").each(function(){
        var filter1 = $(this).find('.filtercheck').attr('id');
        if ($(this).find('input.filtercheck').attr('checked')) {
            $(".itemswrap .item").hide();
            $('.' + filter1).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How 'bout this:

```
function refreshDynamicDivs() {
    $(".filtercheck").each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("."+id).show();
        }
        else {
            $("."+id).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because checked does not return a boolean value use prop instead, but in your case you can use `:checked` pseudo and check the result length.

Code:

```
$("button").click(function () {
                $(".itemswrap .item").hide();
    $(".lifilter").each(function () {
        var filter1 = $(this).find('.filtercheck').attr('id');
        if ($(this).find('input.filtercheck:checked').length>0) {
            $('.' + filter1).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c6jrxhzk/

Comment: @wharry in what event you want to fire the filters?